# Dropzone not validating maximum number of files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone for uploading files , I have set the file limitations upto maximum six files, this code is working if I upload one image at a time, but if I select more then six images by pressing control button at the start of uploading files then it does not validate the files and uploads all files. I am using laravel for backend, My code is:-

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
    paramName: "file", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
    maxFilesize: 1, // MB
    maxFiles: 6,
    acceptedFiles: ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif",
    clickable: true,
    init: function () {
        this.on("success", function(file, responseText) {
            file.previewTemplate.setAttribute('id',responseText[0].id);
        });
        this.on("thumbnail", function(file) {
            if (file.width < 350 || file.height < 200) {
                file.rejectDimensions()
            }
            else {
                file.acceptDimensions();
            }
        });
    },
    accept: function(file, done) {
        file.acceptDimensions = done;
        file.rejectDimensions = function() { done("Image width or height should be greater than 350*200"); };
    },
    removedfile: function(file){
        var name = file.name; 
        $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: ajax_url+'listing/deleteListingImage/'+name,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
            var _ref;
            return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;
            },   
            dictDefaultMessage: "Drop your files to upload"
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: A. Any errors in the `console`? B. Have your read the [docs about it](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-maxFiles)? It's not validate, it's just call the event `maxfilesexceeded `.

Comment: Its validating fine the only problem is in the case if I upload more then six images at once

Comment: Also not giving any error in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the extra files using the method [`removeFile(file)`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods) when [`maxfilesexceeded`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-maxfilesexceeded) is called.

Like this:

```js
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  maxFiles: 2,
  autoProcessQueue: false,
  init: function(){
    var myDropZone = this;
    myDropZone.on('maxfilesexceeded', function(file) {
      myDropZone.removeFile(file);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/dropzone.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/4.3.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>
<form action="/file-upload"
      class="dropzone"
      id="my-awesome-dropzone">

</form>
```

http://output.jsbin.com/dodajij

Comment: Why we set autoProcessQueue : false, is it for not to upload files automatically ? because when we are adding this code nothing happens and if we remove autoprocessQueue it is still uploading all files, not removing extra files.

Comment: Sure: `autoProcessQueue: false` it's just for the demo because I have no server to handle the request form. You should remove it.

Comment: I got where the error is, we are using accept function in our code for validating dimensions of file as i have mentioned it in my code, if I remove that accept function then your code is working fine for me. Is there any alternate of accept function ?